# Moving tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a window by removing its title bar. I made the window move when the user click and drag using a mouse. Now if I click inside any widget and drag, the window is moving. But I want to the make it move only if the user clicks outside the widgets. Any suggestions will be helpful. Here is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
    
win = Tk()
win.geometry('200x200')
win.overrideredirect(True)

offsetx = 0
offsety = 0

lst = ['Sample 1', 'Sample 2', 'Sample 3', 'Sample 4']
    
def drag(event):
    x = win.winfo_pointerx() - win.offsetx
    y = win.winfo_pointery() - win.offsety
    win.geometry('+{x}+{y}'.format(x=x,y=y))

def click(event):
    win.offsetx = event.x
    win.offsety = event.y


win.bind('<Button-1>', click)
win.bind('<B1-Motion>', drag)
            
lb1 = Listbox(win)
lb1.pack()

b1 = Button(win, text='Close', command=win.destroy).pack()

for i in range(len(lst)):
    lb1.insert(i, lst[i])

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try to set a container, maybe Frame, do what you did to win to frame, like binds, listbox, button, ...

Comment: @JasonYang I have tried what you told. Still it behaves same as how previously it was.

Comment: I think you should get something wrong, show one script for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here, I use a Frame as container, not root window.
It will show a window, top area is for list box and maybe 10 lines default, bottom area with one button and two box of drak green area. Here click-and-drag on list box and button won't move the window, but those two dark green area work.

[image]

```
from tkinter import *

def mouse_down(event):
    global x, y
    x, y = event.x, event.y

def mouse_up(event):
    global x, y
    x, y = None, None

def mouse_drag(event):
    global x, y
    try:
        deltax = event.x - x
        deltay = event.y - y
        x0 = win.winfo_x() + deltax
        y0 = win.winfo_y() + deltay
        win.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x0, y0))
    except:
        pass

win = Tk()
# win.geometry('200x400')
win.overrideredirect(True)

x, y = None, None

frame = Frame(win, background='#004000')
frame.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', mouse_down)
frame.bind('<B1-Motion>', mouse_drag)
frame.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', mouse_up)
frame.pack()

list_box = Listbox(frame)
list_box.pack()

button = Button(frame, text='Close', command=win.destroy)
button.pack()

lst = ['Sample 1', 'Sample 2', 'Sample 3', 'Sample 4']
for i, item in enumerate(lst):
    list_box.insert(i, item)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the simplest thing to do is just check which window received the event in the drag function, and only do the drag if it's the root window:

```
def drag(event):
    if event.widget == win:
        x = win.winfo_pointerx() - win.offsetx
        y = win.winfo_pointery() - win.offsety
        win.geometry('+{x}+{y}'.format(x=x,y=y))
```

Or, if you want to be able to drag while clicking in intermediate windows you could check the class of the widget:

```
def drag(event):
    window_class = event.widget.winfo_class()
    if window_class in ("Tk", "Toplevel", "Frame"):
        x = win.winfo_pointerx() - win.offsetx
        y = win.winfo_pointery() - win.offsety
        win.geometry('+{x}+{y}'.format(x=x,y=y))
```

Answer (score 0):

how about creating a title bar canvas with tkinter and keybind to the title bar, instead of the whole application?

```
titlebar_canvas = tk.Canvas(win, height=20, width=200)
titlebar_canvas.pack(side='top')
titlebar_canvas.bind('<Button-1>', click)
titlebar_canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', drag)
```

Comment: I need to restrict the movement of window only inside the widgets. It should move if we click on all other locations.